# How i can open vaadin menu bar

Tags: java, web-applications, vaadin

I have standart vaadin example:

```
    MenuBar settings = new MenuBar();
    MenuItem settingsMenu = settings.addItem("",
            null);
    settingsMenu.setIcon(new ThemeResource("loupe.ico"));
    settingsMenu.setStyleName("icon-cog");
    settingsMenu.addItem("Settings", cmd);
    settingsMenu.addItem("Preferences", cmd);
    settingsMenu.addSeparator();
    settingsMenu.addItem("My Account", cmd);
```

How i can programmatically open menu or select one of his points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far a I know you can not. Opening and closing a menu does not communicate with the server (tried in debug mode), so the state of the menu is not known to the server and can't be changed. I also checked the sources and could not find any sign that it should be possible somehow (see [VMenuBar.java](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin/blob/master/client/src/com/vaadin/client/ui/VMenuBar.java) and [MenuBarConnector.java](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin/blob/master/client/src/com/vaadin/client/ui/menubar/MenuBarConnector.java)).